# document.getElementById('articleTitle').value don't work

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I create these code in my web application

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('articleTitle').value =  "Ehsan" ;
</script>`
```

but in result my input has no value

my input is:

```
<input id="articleTitle" name="articleTitle" class="input-xxlarge" 
type="text" placeholder="title">
```

my javascript code is above the html code

Comment: try to put your procedure into window.onload

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure the element exists before you try to retrieve it. If your `script` is above the `input` in the HTML source, for instance, the element won't exist when the script runs.

You can either move your `script` tag underneath the `input`, which will work, or use a "DOM ready" event of some kind. Putting the `script` tag at the end of the `body` element is recommend by the [YUI team](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [others](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41) recommend just ensuring the script is below the element it works with.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a function to an event, by example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
  document.getElementById('articleTitle1').value ="Ehsan";}
</script>
<input id="articleTitle" name="articleTitle" class="input-xxlarge" 
type="text" placeholder="title" onclick="test();">
```

I hope to help!